# What are the typical reasons for a .net access denied error on attempting to log in to Sitecore?

Tags: .net, sitecore, sitecore6

Using a valid Sitecore account, no roles associated but marked as Administrator, I got the error below when trying to log in.

1. The site is running OK
2. I was able to log in with a similar account.
3. Attempting to log in with an incorrect password returns the correct "Access denied" message on the login page.
4. The login worked OK again a short while later (roughly an hour)

What would the typical reasons be for Sitecore to fail in this way?

Error details:

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Application access denied. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details:

Sitecore.Exceptions.AccessDeniedException: Application access denied.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[AccessDeniedException: Application access denied.]
   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.HasAccess(Boolean accessAllowed, String message) +158
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ShellForm.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +68

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks) +640
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +38
   System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) +35
   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CallMethod(Type type, Object obj, String methodName, Boolean includeNonPublic, Boolean includeInherited, Object[] parameters) +37
   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CallMethod(Object obj, String methodName, Boolean includeNonPublic, Boolean includeInherited, Object[] parameters) +66
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +420
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3064

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.237

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem where I locked all my users out after trying to define some custom roles.

The problem was that users no longer belonged to the magic role **sitecore\Sitecore Client Authoring**.

The other **sitecore\Sitecore Client XXX** roles are also special. For example, belonging to **sitecore\Sitecore Client Publishing** shows the publishing ribbon.

Comment: My Administrator account has no roles, it uses the Administrator checkbox to override and role based security. I wasn't locked out or disabled, I got a .Net error page.

Comment: Just to be clear -- we're not talking about the 'admin' user, right? Are you still able to reproduce the error? Can you use the 'access viewer' tool in user manager to confirm that this user doesn't have read access to any system items explicitly denied? Finally, are there any warning or error messages in your application log immediately preceding this exception?

Comment: Not the default Sitecore admin user, no, but a user with "Administrator" privileges checked and no roles assigned. There doesn't look to be anything much in the log preceding the error, no.

Answer (score 0):

Really strange thing. Having Administrator check box enabled disables all security checks in Sitecore. Tried this on 6.5

Comment: Yes, and no. At least in 6.4 an Administrator account can still have access explicitly denied to items. It's not actually reccomended practice to log in with an Administrator account. Being able to override all settings makes the account unpredictable, as it may bypass some settings or pipelines.